# Min exponent range in normalized floating-point system

Tags: numerical-methods, computational-mathematics

In a floating-point system with precision $t = 6$ decimal digits, let $x = 1.23456$ and
$y = 1.23579$.

(a) If the floating-point system is normalized, what is the minimum exponent range for which
$x$, $y$, and $y-x$ are all exactly representable?

(b) Is the difference $y-x$ exactly representable, regardless of exponent range, if gradual under-flow is allowed? Why?

**My attempt:** My current thought is for part (a), by shifting the decimal points after normalizing, the min. exponent range is [-5,-1] for $x$ and $y$ and $[-6,-3]$ for $y-x$? Is this true though? If it's not, can anyone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $x$ and $y$ have six digits each, you must have an exponent of $0$ available to represent them exactly.  Then $x=1.23456E0$.  Since $y-x=0.00123$ we can normalize it by writing it as $1.23000E-3$ To fit all of this we need an exponent range of at least $[-3,0]$  If we allow gradual underflow, we can represent $y-x$ exactly as $0.00123E0$ and as long as we have an exponent of $0$ available we can represent all three.

Comment: Many thanks for your explanation. I have a question: if we allow graduate underflow, why we can represent $y-x$ exactly as $0.00123E0$ if our exponent range doesn't contain 0?

Comment: I said it had to contain $0$, but didn't have to contain anything else.

Comment: I meant because the problem asked if the difference y−x is exactly representable REGARDLESS of the exponent range, and from your explanation, I wonder if the answer is "no" if we have an exponent range like [−2,−1]

Comment: $y-x$ is exactly representable as long as you have some number in the range $[-3,0]$ available.  If your range is $[-2,-1]$ you could have $0.12300E-2$ or $0.01230E-1$. In that case you can't represent either $x$ or $y$.

Comment: in case the range is $[-2,-1]$, I won't be able to represent $y-x$ exactly? I think part (b) singles out any range for $y-x$ only (so we don't need to worry about whether a specific range works for $x$ and $y$). For this reason, the answer to the original question should be "no"?

Comment: Yes, you can represent $y-x$ exactly in that case.  That is what I said last time.  As I read the original question, the answer should be no, in that if the exponent range is $[-8,-6]$, you can't represent $y-x$, but that seems silly.